# please help fix script creating daily portfolio value with $ change and % change

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet with two sheets (Portfolio and daily). I have a script that will create a new entry with date and total balance (from B59 on portfolio sheet). This will always be added at row 4, pushing all previous entries down one row, keeping current date at top (current result is like table 1).

I would like to get the result in table 2. This would copy over 3 cells (B59,B60,B61) and also create a $ change entry and a % change entry. The dollar change entry would always subtract B5 from B4 and the percent change entry would also always use B4 and B5. The results should stay in column E and F of each row (not be over written)but move down with the rest of the data

I was working on a different script where I got the 3 cells to copy over, but had to freeze the first 3 rows and was having problems with blank cells being added when I tried doing the $ change formula. I never even got to try the percent formula. The main problem I was having is that the new row would be created with E4 blank, and any formula I tried for A4 minus A5 would work fine for existing rows but would be pushed down a row.

I hope I've explained myself well and appreciate any help

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DAILY |  |  |  |  |
| date | total Balance |  |  |  |
| (blank) |  |  |  |  |
| 6/25/2021 | 500 |  |  |  |
| 6/24/2021 | 475 |  |  |  |

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DAILY |  |  |  |  |  |
| date | total Balance | account 1 | account 2 |  |  |
| (blank) |  |  |  |  |  |
| 6/25/2021 | 500 | 210 | 290 | $ change | % change |
| 6/24/2021 | 475 | 200 | 275 | $ change | % change |

```
    function logPortfolioValuedaily() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var overview = sheet.getSheetByName("Portfolio");
  sheet.getSheetByName("daily").insertRowBefore(4)
  var history = sheet.getSheetByName("daily");
  
  var PortfolioValue = overview.getRange("A59");

  var col = 1;
  var row = 3;
  
  do{
    row++;
    
  }while(!history.getRange(row,col).isBlank())
  
  var pvHistDate = history.getRange(row,col);  
  var pvHist = history.getRange(row,col+1);
  
  
  pvHist.setValue(PortfolioValue.getValue());
  pvHistDate.setValue(new Date());
};
```

new formula

```
function recordHistory() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var inputSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Portfolio");
var source = inputSheet.getRange("A59:D59");
var values = source.getValues();
// first 4 rows of spreadsheet frozen

values[0][0] = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "M/d/yyyy");


var outputSheet = ss.getSheetByName("daily")

outputSheet.appendRow(values[0]);outputSheet.sort(1,false)
}
```

Comment: Hi there @TonyR! I don't completely understand your goal, can you show an example? Also please explain why your script doesn't fulfill your goal.

Comment: Hi Jacques, I'm sorry I didn't respond earlier. I just noticed you replied. Thank you for trying to help. I've been working on the second formula I mentioned and I got it almost exactly where I need it. I would like to make one change that I can't figure out. I would like all new rows to always be inserted at row 5. I've tried using insertrowbefore(5) in a number of different spots to no avail. Freezing the first 4 rows works but I would like to have it work without the need to freeze. I've edited my post to include the new formula. thanks